# Trying to install mangoose in my system Giving error 404 not found mangoose@latest

Tags: node.js, npm

C:\xampp\htdocs\meanPro>npm install --save mangoose
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: mangoose@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\neha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-07-08T05_51_32_956Z-debug.log

Error while installing mangoose. Please help.

Comment: Did you mean to type [`mongoose`](http://mongoosejs.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

You made a small typo, it is mongoose and not mangoose.
Try:

```
npm install --save mongoose
```